# Adding JSON syntax highlighting to IntelliJ IDEA for .liquid files

Tags: json, intellij-idea, webstorm, syntax-highlighting, liquid

I have been able to add syntax highlighting to my `.liquid` files by following the instructions here: [Enabling Liquid templating syntax highlight in webStorm/phpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123188/enabling-liquid-templating-syntax-highlight-in-webstorm-phpstorm?answertab=active#tab-top)

It worked fine for my HTML and liquid syntax highlighting as it's so similar to Twig.

But my issue is I also have my `schema` included in each of my `.liquid` templates. The schema is JSON but there's not syntax highlighting on it at all.

Is there a way to add a custom syntax highlighting for a file type if it's wrapped in some sort of delimiter?

My schema is wrapped like so:

```
{% schema %}
  JSON object with my settings/configuration
{% endschema %}
```

See image below:
[image]

Comment: This type of configuration is only possible by writing a plugin; you can't configure this in the settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @yole have said: you cannot do that. Well... permanently.

You can always inject JSON there manually .. and it will last for  a while (a session for sure).

Just place caret just after `{% schema %}` and hit <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Choose `Inject language or reference` and locate `JSON` in the list (speed search works there as well, so just start typing).

[image]

Result is obvious:

[image]

---

You are using **Twig plugin** for `.liquid` files (native support for them ([RUBY-7210](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-7210)) does not seem to be on JetBrains short list right now).

It's now possible to have permanent Language Injection in custom Twig tag (using Twig plugin). See the screenshot below for custom injection rule that you can create yourself:

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject JSON in your `{% schema %}` block manually via `Alt+Enter`, *Inject language or reference* > *JSON*:

[image]

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/12/twig-handling-improvements/

Answer (score 0):

- At my org we use a custom `.amg` filetype for an internal framework that is essentially just a JSON
- I made `IntelliJ` treat those as JSONs by adding `*.amg` pattern under `Recognized File Types` > `JSON`

[image]

reference: [JetBrains / File type associations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains added support for permanent language references using annotations. Here is sample from PhpStorm for PHP (pretty sure, that something similar you should have for your language as well)

[image]

After that string will be nicely formatted

[image]